# Caching dataset passing value or reference?

Tags: asp.net, caching, dataset, cache-expiration

I'm going to cache an object.  Obvious and popular check before read policy from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227644(v=vs.80).aspx

```
if (Cache["customerDataSet"] == null)
{
    dataSet = DataSetConfiguration.CustomerDataSet;
    Cache["customerDataSet"] = dataSet;
}
else
{
    dataSet = (DataSet)Cache["customerDataSet"];
}
```

secures existence of dataSet object. As dataSet is only a reference to an object, actual dataSet in cache can be gone in milliseconds, for example, in the middle of foreach loop.
If so, this:

```
dataSet = ((DataSet)Cache["customerDataSet"]).Copy();
```

should be safer. Although cache can still expire during .Copy(). Am I right or this is just overthinking?

Comment: Your last sentence is is true ;)

Comment: Cache is volatile, so I used ApplicationState but still thinking cache could better serve.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test:

```
DataSet d = (DataSet)Cache["myKey"];
int i = 0;
do
{
  i++;
} while (Cache["myKey"] != null);

Label1.Text = (Cache["myKey"] == null ? "gone with wind  " : null) + d.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString() + " took: " + i.ToString();
```

the do-while ends  when cache is gone and dataset d is still  accessible. You were right - overthinking.